# Magento 2: Store in array level 3 category using Rest API

Tags: rest, magento2

I'm using REST API with Magento 2.2.3. Below you can see the JSON response when I try to get the category tree.

```
{
"id": 2,
"parent_id": 1,
"name": "Only Beauty",
"is_active": true,
"position": 1,
"level": 1,
"product_count": 0,
"children_data": [
    {
        "id": 1372323,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "name": "Cura della Pelle",
        "is_active": true,
        "position": 1,
        "level": 2,
        "product_count": 0,
        "children_data": [
            {
                "id": 1372335,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Creme Idratanti Viso",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 1,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1372377,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Taglie da Viaggio",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 2,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1372535,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Detergenti Viso",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 3,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1375522,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Struccanti",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 4,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1375540,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Altri Prodotti per la Pelle",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 5,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1375649,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Esfolianti & Scrubs",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 6,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1375716,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Anti-Età",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 7,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1375816,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Prodotti per Cura Occhi",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 8,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1375930,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Maschere & Esfolianti",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 9,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1376342,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Prodotti Pelle per Uomo",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 10,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1376883,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Creme da Notte",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 11,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1486731,
                "parent_id": 1372323,
                "name": "Controllo Acne e Macchie della Pelle",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 12,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1372324,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "name": "Fragranze",
        "is_active": true,
        "position": 2,
        "level": 2,
        "product_count": 0,
        "children_data": [
            {
                "id": 1372341,
                "parent_id": 1372324,
                "name": "Per Lui",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 1,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1372347,
                "parent_id": 1372324,
                "name": "Per Lei",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 2,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1372583,
                "parent_id": 1372324,
                "name": "Unisex",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 3,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to store in array the ID of all level 3 subcategory using rest API request.

I tried to get ID using the following code:

```
$authToken = getToken();
$cat = getCategory( $authToken );

foreach ( $cat["children_data"] as $key => $row ) {

    if ( $row["level"] == 3 ) {

        $array_cat[] = $row["id"];


    }

  }
```

This is the API request function:

```
function getCategory( $token ) {

$ch = curl_init( "https://www.onlybeauty.shop/rest/V1/categories/" );

curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
    ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
));

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

if( $response === FALSE ) {

    die( curl_error( $ch ) );

}

$responseData = json_decode( $response, TRUE );

return $responseData;

}
```

Seems that this code works only for level 2 subcategory.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works only for level 2 because you need to go deeper in the "array-tree" of decoded json categories response.

Meaning your foreach procedure should be something like this:

```
$my_data = json_decode($my_json, 1);
print_r($my_data);

$level2_cat = $my_data["children_data"];
foreach($level2_cat as $key=>$row){

    print_r($row["children_data"][0]["level"]);
}
```

Just tried an example with a sample of your json and with this you print the level of the third level category. Hope it helps